# LogCat shows exception in SyncProcessorQueue every 5 seconds

Tags: logging, system-error

I just started noticing this in my Logcat, it seems like every 5 seconds I get this exception caught. Does anyone have any idea what app or part of the OS it could be? I can't imagine whatever this is constantly running and throwing exceptions can be good for my battery, this occurs whether the screen is on or off.

Phone is moto Atrix, android 2.3

I wonder what is `com.google.apps.dots`?

```
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593): Caught unexpected error
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.provider.BlobStore.addToPossibleStores(BlobStore.java:98)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.provider.BlobStore.getPossibleStores(BlobStore.java:108)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.CleanUpSync$OldAttachmentAndBlobCleanUp.syncSelf(CleanUpSync.java:138)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.BaseSyncNode.syncSelfInternal(BaseSyncNode.java:121)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.BaseSyncNode.sync(BaseSyncNode.java:104)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.BaseSyncNode.syncNextChild(BaseSyncNode.java:196)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.BaseSyncNode.sync(BaseSyncNode.java:107)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.BaseSyncNode.syncNextChild(BaseSyncNode.java:196)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.BaseSyncNode.sync(BaseSyncNode.java:107)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.BaseSyncNode.syncNextChild(BaseSyncNode.java:196)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.BaseSyncNode.sync(BaseSyncNode.java:107)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.BaseSyncNode.syncNextChild(BaseSyncNode.java:196)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.BaseSyncNode.sync(BaseSyncNode.java:107)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.SyncNodeProcessor.syncNextNode(SyncNodeProcessor.java:34)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.SyncProcessorQueue.process(SyncProcessorQueue.java:134)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.SyncProcessorQueue.process(SyncProcessorQueue.java:114)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.SyncProcessorQueue.access$200(SyncProcessorQueue.java:31)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at com.google.apps.dots.android.app.sync.SyncProcessorQueue$Processor.run(SyncProcessorQueue.java:236)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-19 17:51:47.455: E/SyncProcessorQueue(27593):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: I think that might be related to Google Currents, from what I've seen in other logs. Do you have that installed?

Comment: @eldarerathis, yes it is installed. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It has the package name right there-- 
"com.google.apps.dots" 
Everything after that are the classes and related classes to that error. 

com.google.android.apps.currents is the package name for Currents. 

If you can get rid of that package, it should solve the issue. 

--

Comment: Maybe there's an update already in Play Store that fixes up the null pointer exception...

Answer (score 2):

As per [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/mobile/android-devices/f30GYm1_mk0) thread, it's related to Google Currents. Either disable the automatic syncing feature of Currents or uninstall Currents completely to get rid of this error.

I don't think it's a "bad" error though and should not cause any other problems (such as battery drain, etc.)